# How can I call a dynamic id?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My code is like this :

```
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<5; $i++) {

?>
        <button type="submit" id="test<?php echo $i ?>">
            test <?php echo $i ?>
        </button>
<?php
    }
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    for(var i=0; i < 5; i++) {        
        $("#test"+i).click(function(){
            console.log('test'+i);
        });
    }
</script>
```

When I click button anything, the result :

> test5

Should when I click button test 0, the result : test0

Why it does not work?

Comment: You can print the ID directly by doing `console.log(this.id);` instead of `console.log('test'+i);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do it in this way. because `i` will be always `5`.

```js
for(var i=0; i < 5; i++) {        
  $("#test"+i).click(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
 }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" id="test0">test 0</button>
<button type="submit" id="test1">test 1</button>
<button type="submit" id="test2">test 2</button>
<button type="submit" id="test3">test 3</button>
<button type="submit" id="test4">test 4</button>
```

**ALSO**

it's better to use a `class` attribute in this case

like this

```js
$(".test").click(function(){
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" class="test">test 0</button>
<button type="submit" class="test">test 1</button>
<button type="submit" class="test">test 2</button>
<button type="submit" class="test">test 3</button>
<button type="submit" class="test">test 4</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `let` instead of `var`in your loop.